# How to enable Virtualization in Windows 10 with GA-Z77X-UD3H motherboard

Tags: windows-10, cpu, motherboard, virtualization, hyper-v

***I'm going to ask and answer my own question, since I didn't find a straight answer to this problem anywhere.***

I have a 2013 vintage PC that is still a well-running workhorse that I don't want to replace. The PC has a GA-Z77X-UD3H motherboard, and an Intel Core i7-3770K Processor. The processor specs say that it does support VT-x virtualization.

I bought the PC with Windows 7 Professional installed, but later accepted the upgrade to Windows 10 Professional. I have struggled to get apps working that require "Hyper-V" and "Virtualization" to be enabled in Windows 10. Two apps in particular are:

- Android Studio for Windows (I wanted the emulator)
- Docker for Windows

In the Task Manager "Performance" tab, under the "CPU" category, it says "Virtualization: Disabled" among other property values. I can't figure out how to reconfigure the PC such that I get "Virtualization: Enabled".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were a few things going on that, when combined, made this difficult to fix. They are:

- The PC was originally configured to run a Windows 7 Professional operating system, and "Hyper-V" was not part of the Windows operating system until Windows 8
- The motherboard model/BIOS was from a time when VT-x was new-ish, and the BIOS settings labels do not make it easy to get the settings right to enable VT-x support
- This model of motherboard seems to have a weird quirk of not always saving the modified BIOS setting to its flash memory unless you fully power down the system (rather than just a system restart)

**THE SOLUTION**

The easiest part to solve was enabling "Hyper-V" on the PC. There are plenty of resources online (and here in Super User) to guide you through this part. In short, ensure that "Hyper-V" support is enabled on your PC.

The difficult part to solve was getting that "Virtualization: Disabled" flipped to "Virtualization: Enabled". After a lot of struggling, I finally isolated the issue to the motherboard BIOS settings.

I did **MUCH** online research for a solution that works for my motherboard, which is a GA-Z77X-UD3H. The age of the motherboard contributed to this, since it was manufactured at a time when VT-x was not widely used. There was no setting in the BIOS that explicitly says "Enabled VT-x". The closest thing was "Intel Virtualization Technology". Enabling that one setting did **NOT** get the job done.

I ended up using trial-and-error to enable a number of things in the BIOS. I'm not sure what magic combination of settings got the job done. **I took screenshots of the relevant BIOS settings screens that I will include below to assist others who have the same (or similar) motherboard and BIOS.**

One other important note about this model of motherboard. Mine didn't always permanently retain the BIOS settings that I changed if I only did a restart. It did seem to keep those changes if I did a full power-down (and disconnected my UPS just to be extra sure). I don't know why this happens, but it just does sometimes, so you might want to go back into the BIOS and confirm your changes if you first attempt is not successful.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**And now look how happy it is!**

[image]

**And now Docker for Windows works!**

[image]

Comment: I tested a lot of variants...
`Intel Virtualization Technology: Enabled` AND `OS Type: Windows 8` did the the trick! 
THANKS